# Get the list of directories and sub directories using Git API

Tags: github

Please advise if it's possible to get the list of directories and sub-directories via GitHub API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the content of a file or directory in a repository, with the [Repository Content API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

> The response will be an array of objects, one object for each item in the directory.

Look for the entries of `"type": "dir"`

This won't be recursive though: you will need to repeat the process for each subdirectory.